# Data transfer between c++ modules

Tags: c++, oop, network-programming, osi

I have a very generic question. I am trying to communicate between two modules at the two layers of OSI (suppose Transport layer is implemented in class A and class B implements network layer). What I understand is that class A can simply use class B by calling its methods to forward a data payload further to the lower layers. Therefore, class A has the knowledge of class B but not vice versa.

The questions is, when class B receives data from the lower layers, how is the data forwarded to class A (upper layer) as it does not know about class A. How is such a functionality implemented in C++? What are the important topic to learn for this kind of task?

Comment: This is an abstract question. There are no rules of any kind of this nature in C++. When designing an application like that, it is up to you, completely, to define and implement all the rules.

Comment: Object A could *poll* object B for data. Or set a *callback* that B calls once it receives data. Or something else completely. This question can have *many* answers, and is to broad.

Comment: I guess it also depends a fair bit on what hardware you have. If this is some fast system like a microcontroller or DSP, you might have to sacrifice OOD for speed. If the system is some slow thing like a PC, then you have all the time in the world.

Answer (score 0):

Simply by writing setter/getter functions in the network layer class. When the transport layer class is updated, it reads the network data through a getter function.

It might even make sense to make the network a private member of transport, since transport can never exist without network.

Start by drawing up all class dependencies with pen and paper. Revise them a couple of times until you have a design which seems to make the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

The way it works in the kernel is that the transport layer registers a callback in the network layer. When the network layer receives a datagram that must be transmitted to the network layer it call this callback function passing the payload of the network layer datagram. The network layer datagram knows it must pass the payload of the datagram to a specific transport layer protocol because of one specific field indicating the upper layer protocol. In the case of IPv4 datagram, it is field [Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Protocol).

You can implement this callback in C++ in different ways:

1. Class A registers to class B for receiving messages destined to Protocol X. This can be done using the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).
2. Class A registers a callback method or a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) in B, for Protocol X.

When B receives a datagram for Protocol X, it notifies observers registered for that protocol or it calls the registered callback or lambda.